# Can we get unique transaction id from app store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store

I want to access transaction id or something unique id when the app is first purchased and downloaded from app store.

So that I can identify that user with that unique id, and send that id to my server.

Is this possible to get that from app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a unique transaction ID from an In-App-Purchase, but not from the original download or app purchase from the iTunes App store.  Neither of these identify the user.  Apple's privacy policy may prevent them from ever giving you this information from their app store data.

Answer (score 1):

Previously you would use the device id, but that is now deprecated by Apple. I would recommend you simply generate a new GUID when the app is first launched, store that in the user defaults, and use that.

There isn't any way to access transaction information from your app.

Comment: actually i am doing Inapp purchase,for that i need original purchase date and that unique transaction id.So on that basis i will calculate renewal  after 1 year of purchase date.